# Apache tomcat 8.0 server unable to compile the jsps

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am getting below issue by using apache tomcat 8.0:

> Sep 02, 2015 12:20:33 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1
>   findType SEVERE: Compilation error
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.(ClassFileReader.java:372)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:165)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1237)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromVariantTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1293)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeArgumentsFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1080)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1242)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:509)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:590)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:329)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:674)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:653)

Comment: Thankyou, after replacing the apache tomcat 8.0 in the eclipse its working as expected

Answer (score 1):

Remove existing localhost servers and add new server. This will solve your problem.